# I could not upload on wagtail admin when my project was deployed to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I uploaded image files on wagtail, although it is going well to read image title but images itself was destroyed. so the titles is showed on the display of both admin and user side.

I browsed through some blogs and websites on media and static, but this problem has not been resolved for almost three days.

**Development environment**

```
python==3.7.3
Django==3.2.6
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2==2.9.1
wagtail==2.14
whitenoise==5.3.0
DB == postgres
server == Heroku stack-18
```

**my try and error**

*①added the follow code to urls.py*

python

```
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

*②changed like follow*

```py
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
    ↓
    application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

**related code (those are possible to relate into this problem)**

```py
    #production.py    
    from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
    import dj_database_url
    
    import os
    from .base import *
    
    #省略
    
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
    
    COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
    COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = [
        'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
        'compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter',
    ]
    
    COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD = 'content'
    
    #省略
```

```py
    #urls.py
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS) +
    static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

```py
    #wsgi.py
    import os
    from dj_static import Cling
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    
    application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
    
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "squjap.settings.production")
```

```py
    #base.py
    
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ]
    
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
    
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')]
        
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I really want your help, Thank yoooou

Comment: Are you storing uploads on Amazon S3 or some other off-dyno service? If not, I suggest you start now. Otherwise you'll "fix" this issue but then lose your uploads whenever your dyno restarts (at least daily).

Comment: Thanks replying me!! yes, I have the experience where you said, so I will try to manage it. but now, I am suffering from what I write. Do you think using S3 resolve that?